# Running "mvn test site" giving [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project

Tags: maven, selenium, xslt

I'm trying to generate xslt report using reporty-ng with Testng+maven but getting error as

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project Selenium Project: failed to get report for org.reportyng:reporty-ng: Plugin org.reportyng:reporty-ng:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.reportyng:reporty-ng:jar:1.2 in https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of reporty-ng has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Below is the part of the pom.xml:

```
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<reporting>
<plugins>
        <!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <!-- Output directory for the testng xslt report -->
                <outputDir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir>
                    <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                    <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
                    <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
            </configuration>     
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>reporty-ng</id>
        <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Consider using ExtentReports instead of ReportNG, since the latter is no longer supported.  http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of this, if you run "mvn clean verify", that will include the "site" phase of the build as well as the tests.   You shouldn't need to explicitly call the site phase and so don't do it.   Also, if you were to explicitly call the "site" phase, you should probably include the site plugin as a dependency, don't you think?

In my experience with both TestNG reports and ReportNG reports, the site plugin is not related to the report output.  The site plugin is only related to the "Surefire" (or Failsafe) plugins reporting phase output.  In other words, you will notice that the default output folder of Surefire plugin is directly related to the standard output location of "site" plugin, in general.  This can be very confusing, I agree.

Also, I [would configure](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html) it (possibly) like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
    <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>    
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire/reportng</outputDirectory>
        <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
        <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
        <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
    </configuration>     
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9</version>
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site</outputDirectory>
    <reportsDirectories>
        <reportsDirectories>${basedir}/target/surefire</reportsDirectories>
    </reportsDirectories>
</configuration>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <reports>
                <report>report-only</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the same way in which you suggested in above configuration and run with command as "mvn clean verify". Although Build Success observed but no reportng file generated. Could you help me & let me know in case something wrong here?

Comment: @Ankit - I would suggest you start by simplifying things.  You should be able to get the ReportNG plugin to work without the maven-site-plugin nor the maven-surefire-report-plugin .  Try to setup ReportNG exactly as the website documentation suggests, without the extra configuration parameters you added.  Then, you should see the ReportNG report being placed within the surefire output folder (by default).

Comment: @Ankit - if it helps, i wrote an example of a TestNG report once. here is the url: https://github.com/djangofan/reportng-example